# Como ler dados de um SQL do postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mongodb

Olá, Boa tarde sou relativamente novo programando, estive trabalhando em um projeto que envolve o mapeamento de alguns equipamentos, fiz a minha parte sem problemas porem agora preciso inserir dados de um outro aplicativo que é meio que o projeto pai do meu.

**O estado atual é esse:**

1.Fiz meu banco de dados com o MongoDB, e o projeto antigo foi feito com o Django usando o postgresql como banco de dados.

2.Tenho o Arquivo Sql da aplicação antiga.

3.Consegui uma parte importante dos dados lendo os arquivos e pegando na mão mesmo

**O problema em questão é o seguinte:**

1.Não consigo pegar ou identificar no arquivo algo que possua a latitude e longitude que é o que preciso

Queria saber se alguém possui uma maneira de ler esse aquivo e visualizá-lo de maneira mais entendível (O que peguei foi no código mesmo )

**Tentei importar mas não consegui, sou bem leigo mexendo com essa parte.**

Comment: O PostGIS não é um banco de dados, é uma extensão espacial desenvolvida sobre o sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados PostgreSQL, que permite o armazenamento e uso de objetos GIS em banco de dados. Veja: https://postgis.net/

Comment: Seria isto https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html ?

Comment: Mil desculpas amigo, realmente errei

Comment: Esse link ensina a fazer a conexão, existe algum modo de apenas observar os dados do sql que possuo ?

Comment: É impossível "observar" os dados de um banco de dados sem fazer uma conexão (entendo "observar" como "ler").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera obrigado mais meu problema era diferente,

Eu não resolvi pelo método convencional mas encontrei as coordenadas, estavam como geometry por isso estranhei,

Peguei o que precisava usando o código mesmo.

Obrigado